# Gamma function computation efficiency?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions

I wonder what kind of algorithm is used to compute the values for the gamma function. Specifically, I am interested in how the computational load increases when the complexity of the input grows.
So, for example, evaluating

```
Gamma[x + I y]
```

for integer `x` and `y` and gradually increasing their number of digits will make the computation time longer. What is the corresponding power law for the increase?

EDIT:
evaluating at `4 Pi + I 8 GoldenRatio`:

```
data = Monitor[
Table[{k, 
 N[Gamma[4 Pi + I 8 GoldenRatio], k 10^3]; // Timing // 
  First}, {k, 1, 10, 5/10}], k]; 
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

Now shows

[image]

and I get

```
line = Fit[Log@data, {1, x}, x]
-3.350 + 2.723 x
```

not sure if this is relevant or just an artifact.

Comment: Try `Exit` or `Quit` before you run the benchmark. It will quite the kernel. Als jus `Gamma[1 + I ]` will work.

Comment: Thank you! Result seems to be fairly consistent across different points in complex plane. Good to know that it is polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this Documentation page: [**Some Notes on Internal Implementation**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

> - For machine precision most special functions use Mathematica-derived rational minimax approximations. The notes that follow apply mainly to
>     arbitrary precision.
> - Gamma uses recursion, functional equations, and the Binet asymptotic formula.

On my machine the power exponent is **2.634**. I wonder how much it depends on the setup. Benchmark it in the same number range and let me know.

```
data = Monitor[
   Table[{k, 
     N[Gamma[Pi + I GoldenRatio], k 10^3]; // Timing // First}, 
   {k, 1, 10, 5/10}], k];

ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

```
line = Fit[Log@data, {1, x}, x]
(* -2.672 + 2.634 x *)
```

It is true I think that Pi and GoldenRatio added a bit complexity. So for just `Gamma[1 + I ]` I got exponent **2.546** consistently.

```
line = Fit[Log@data, {1, x}, x]
(* -2.720 + 2.546 x *)

Show[ListPlot[Log@data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[line, {x, 0, 5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what the line `Gamma[Pi + I GoldenRatio]` in definition for `data` does. Are you evaluating gamma several times at the same point?

Comment: @Kagaratsch yes but with increasing precision driven by growing k*10^3. Mathematica has arbitrary precision, so I picked two numbers that have infinite aperiodic decimal part.

Comment: I get `-2.409 + 2.677 x` for `line = Fit[Log@data, {1, x}, x]`. Looks fairly consistent. And I am currently on a laptop.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Hah, interesting, I would be thrilled to see other folks let us know the exponent. Some neat experiments.

Comment: Now I got some strange behavior at `4 Pi + I 8 GoldenRatio`. See edit of my question above.

Comment: In a small machine http://i.stack.imgur.com/CEOIa.png, `-3.70 + 3.761 x`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are correct about it taking longer and longer. Here's a test which takes the first 1000 terms 2^x insider the gamma function and takes the timing:

```
all = N[Timing[Gamma[2^# + I 2^#]]] & /@ Range[1000];
ListPlot[Transpose[all][[1]]]
```

[image]

This does not show a generally increasing time.

Comment: I think in this case precision is too small to produce TIming growth above error fluctuations.

Comment: Looks like you are right, but what did Vitaliy Kaurov do different?

Comment: @Kagaratsch I used many more digits in precision so times will become significant, above error. See my comment right above yours.

Comment: It looks like Vitaly Kaurov's answer measures the calculation of gamma as the number of desired digits in the answer grows, whereas the above calculates the gamma values for larger values of the arguments.

Comment: Oh, yes, I guess going with just more digits he has a clever way to avoid an overflow and probe with much larger input.

Comment: Maybe, but it also confounds the calculation of Pi and the Goldenratio (to the required accuracies) with the calculation of the Gamma. How to know which is taking the time?

Comment: Substitute `Gamma[Pi + I GoldenRatio]` by just `Pi + I GoldenRatio` to compute the sum of these constants to the given precision instead of the gamma function. It will take no time at all.

Comment: @Kagaratsch It is true I think that Pi and GoldenRatio added a bit complexity. So for just `Gamma[1 + I ]` I got exponent **2.546** consistently. I added it into the answer.